# How to access txpool pending transactions using Netherum?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, blockchain, nethereum

I want to get list of transactions which are in pending state & queued state in txpool. I can see these transactions in pool using txpool.inspect command.
I tried code given in nethereum sample code but that returns pending transactions in current block.

[image: txpool status]